# C++primer 5th about func parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

Its question is" Give the second parameter of make_plural (§ 6.3.2, p. 224) a default argument of 's'. Test your program by printing singular and plural versions of the words success and failure"
here is the make_plural.

```
string make_plural(size_t ctr, const string& word, const string& ending )
{
    return (ctr > 1) ? word + ending : word;
}
```

Does it mean that change the 'ending', but ending is the third parameter, isn't it? 
This question worries me a lot! 
Regards!

Comment: [The errata](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321714114/errata/9780321714114_errata_10-31-12.html) doesn't mention it (but it's old and not recently updated), but it seems to me that your assumption that it's the third argument should be correct.

Comment: after writing 2 completely non-sense comments I finally understood your question ;). Of course it they mean the 3rd parameter. Thats how you usually make a plural: add an "s". Also, providing a default for 2nd but not for the third parameter isnt possible.

Comment: as long as you are passing a string why passing its size in a separate paramter

Comment: @tobi303 I think you're argument that defaulting the second and not third argument is impossible is the best proof that this is in fact an error. Would you be willing to write that up as an answer?

Comment: add more code: how you called it from main

Comment: Re:tobi303. Thank you! And  I'm so sorry for my pool english :(

Comment: Here is the answer i found in github Mooophy/Cpp-Primerstring make_plural(size_t ctr, const string& word, const string& ending = "s")
{
 return (ctr > 1) ? word + ending : word;
}

int main()
{
 cout << "singual: " << make_plural(1, "success", "es") << " "
  << make_plural(1, "failure") << endl;
 cout << "plural : " << make_plural(2, "success", "es") << " "
  << make_plural(2, "failure") << endl;
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That must be a typo.

Looking at the code:

```
string make_plural(size_t ctr, const string& word, const string& ending )
{
    return (ctr > 1) ? word + ending : word;
}
```

the most reasonable thing would be to have "s" as default for `ending`, as this is how you make the plural by default (not always, but with "bee" -> "bees" e.g. it works).

A much stronger argument is that in C++ it is not possible (unless you find a magic workaround (*)) to have a default argument for the n-th parameter if the (n+1)-th has no default argument:

```
foo(int first = 0,int second) // not possible !!
```

With this example it is maybe not so clear why this isnt allowed, but consider having multiple default values. Lets say you would write:

```
foo(int first = 0,int second,int third = 0); // actually still not allowed
```

Then there would be no way to know if

```
foo(1,2);
```

is supposed to call

```
foo(0,1,2);
```

or

```
foo(1,2,0);
```

To resolve this ambiguity some rule had to be invented and for C++ the rule is that default arguments have to be provided from right to left.

(*) If you can change the function and are willing to write some extra code, the workaround is rather trivial. You just have to encapsulate all parameters in a struct that provides creation of parameters with whatever combination of defaults you like.